# Plotting wind vectors on vertical cross-section with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-iris

I've searched high and low but cannot find another answer to this question.

I'm trying to visualise output from the Met Office's Unified Model over the Antarctic Peninsula. At the moment, I have a longitudinal cross section, with potential temperature plotted as filled contours. I would like to plot wind vectors on top of this so they look more like:

[image: Elvidge et al.s' (2014) Fig. 3]

I've tried to adapt the examples for lat/lon coordinates given in 
matplotlib's examples (quiver_demo for instance), but with no luck (probably because I'm doing something wrong that is blindingly obvious).

I have the u, v and w components of wind (although I don't need v because I have taken a slice through one latitude line).

I'm currently using a module called iris (v1.7), which allows me to deal with the files I have (e.g. to convert from a rotated pole projection and convert latitudes/longitudes to sensible coordinates), so please excuse unfamiliar lines in my code.

The code I have is as follows:

```
import iris
import iris.plot as iplt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Load variables from file
fname = ['/pathname/filename.pp']
theta= iris.load_cube(fname,'air_potential_temperature') #all data are 3D 'cubes' of dimensions [x,y,z] = [40,800,800]
U = iris.load_cube(fname, 'eastward_wind')
W = iris.load_cube(fname, 'upward_air_velocity')
lev_ht = theta.coord('level_height').points # for extracting z coordinate only - shape = (40,)

##SPATIAL COORDINATES
## rotate projection to account for rotated pole
var_name = theta
pole_lon = 298.5
pole_lat = 22.99
rotated_lat = var_name.coord('grid_latitude').points
rotated_lon = var_name.coord('grid_longitude').points
real_lon, real_lat = iris.analysis.cartography.unrotate_pole(rotated_lon,rotated_lat, pole_lon, pole_lat)

#define function to find index of gridbox in question
def find_gridbox(x,y):
    global lon_index, lat_index
    lat_index = np.argmin((real_lat-x)**2) #take whole array and subtract lat you want from each point, then find the smallest difference
    lon_index = np.argmin((real_lon-y)**2)
    return lon_index, lat_index

lon_index, lat_index = find_gridbox(-66.58333, -63.166667) # coordinates of Cabinet Inlet

#add unrotated lats/lons into variables
lat = var_name.coord('grid_latitude')
lon = var_name.coord('grid_longitude')
New_lat = iris.coords.DimCoord(real_lat, standard_name='latitude',long_name="grid_latitude",var_name="lat",units=lat.units)
New_lon= iris.coords.DimCoord(real_lon, standard_name='longitude',long_name="grid_longitude",var_name="lon",units=lon.units)

var_names = [theta, U, W]

for var in var_names:
    var.remove_coord('grid_latitude')
    var.add_dim_coord(New_lat, data_dim=1)
    var.remove_coord('grid_longitude')
    var.add_dim_coord(New_lon, data_dim=2)

# Create 2D subsets of data for plotting (longitudinal transects)
theta_slice = theta[:,lat_index,:]
U_slice = U[:,lat_index,:]
W_slice = W[:,lat_index,:]

# Create 2d arrays of lon/alt for gridding
x, y = np.meshgrid(lon.points, lev_ht)
u = U_slice
w = W_slice

# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.set_axis_bgcolor('k') #set orography to be black
ax3 = iplt.contourf(theta_slice, cmap=plt.cm.bwr)
ax1.set_ylim(0,5500)
barbs = plt.quiver(x, y, u, w)
ax3.set_clim(vmin=250, vmax=320)
ax1.set_title('25 May 00:00 UTC', fontsize=28)
ax1.set_ylabel('Height (m)', fontsize=22)
ax1.set_xlabel('Longitude', fontsize=22)
ax1.tick_params(axis='both', which='major', labelsize=18)
plt.colorbar(ax3)
plt.show()
```

However, when the vectors are plotted they appear as lines:

[image: vectors as lines]

I am not sure whether this is because they are too clustered together (when I change line properties like linewidth and scale, the vectors go pretty crazy) or because my inputs are incorrect. The u and w variables are 2D arrays (lon/height) containing the westerly and upward component of wind, respectively, so should contain the magnitude of movement in these directions.

Apologies that I cannot post the actual files: they are in a specific Met Office .pp format (of course) but have similar qualities to netCDF. I have tried to describe the data dimensions in the code comments.

Comment: I would try really simple versions of the barb data -- copy ` x, y, u, w` with `zeros_like`, then add a single arrow in the middle and see if it plots sensibly.

Comment: @cphlewis - good suggestion. You're right, I'm getting some super strange behaviour when I do that, almost like the vector doesn't know when to end. I'm going to have a look at what's going on in the data itself and see if I can figure out what information I'm missing. Thanks.

Comment: Could the units be mismatched?

Comment: @cphlewis I think the problem is that I need to calculate the vectors with u AND v winds first, and then take a vertical cross section of this data in order to get the vectors plotting properly. I'm working on some code to do this now, and will post when I get a working solution.

Answer (score 8):

I hope that you doing well and are able to solve your problem quickly.

Here is some code and the resulting image:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import get_cmap
from matplotlib.colors import from_levels_and_colors
from cartopy import crs
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature, COLORS
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from wrf import (getvar, to_np, get_cartopy, latlon_coords, vertcross,
                 cartopy_xlim, cartopy_ylim, interpline, CoordPair)

wrf_file = Dataset("C:/Users/meteorologia.gmmc/Documents/WRF - Rodada Exemplo/wrfout_exemplo.nc")

# Define the cross section start and end points
cross_start = CoordPair(lat=-8.5, lon=-42)
cross_end = CoordPair(lat=-8.5, lon=-30)

# Get the WRF variables
ht = getvar(wrf_file, "z", timeidx=8)
ht = ht[0:20,:,:]
ter = getvar(wrf_file, "ter", timeidx=8)

w = getvar(wrf_file, "wa", timeidx=8)
w = w[0:20,:,:]

u = getvar(wrf_file, "ua", timeidx=8)
u = u[0:20,:,:]

max_dbz = getvar(wrf_file, "mdbz", timeidx=8)

W = 10**(w/10.) # Use linear Z for interpolation

w_cross = vertcross(W, ht, wrfin=wrf_file,
                    start_point=cross_start,
                    end_point=cross_end,
                    latlon=True, meta=True)

U = 10**(u/10.) # Use linear Z for interpolation

u_cross = vertcross(U, ht, wrfin=wrf_file,
                    start_point=cross_start,
                    end_point=cross_end,
                    latlon=True, meta=True)

# Convert back to dBz after interpolation
w_cross = 10.0 * np.log10(w_cross)
u_cross = 10.0 * np.log10(u_cross)

# Add back the attributes that xarray dropped from the operations above
w_cross.attrs.update(w_cross.attrs)
w_cross.attrs["description"] = "destaggered w-wind component"
w_cross.attrs["units"] = "m s-1"

# Add back the attributes that xarray dropped from the operations above
u_cross.attrs.update(u_cross.attrs)
u_cross.attrs["description"] = "destaggered u-wind component"
u_cross.attrs["units"] = "m s-1"

# To remove the slight gap between the dbz contours and terrain due to the
# contouring of gridded data, a new vertical grid spacing, and model grid
# staggering, fill in the lower grid cells with the first non-missing value
# for each column.

# Make a copy of the z cross data. Let's use regular numpy arrays for this.
w_cross_filled = np.ma.copy(to_np(w_cross))
u_cross_filled = np.ma.copy(to_np(u_cross))

# For each cross section column, find the first index with non-missing
# values and copy these to the missing elements below.
for i in range(w_cross_filled.shape[-1]):
    column_vals = w_cross_filled[:,i]
    # Let's find the lowest index that isn't filled. The nonzero function
    # finds all unmasked values greater than 0. Since 0 is a valid value
    # for dBZ, let's change that threshold to be -200 dBZ instead.
    first_idx = int(np.transpose((column_vals > -200).nonzero())[0])
    w_cross_filled[0:first_idx, i] = w_cross_filled[first_idx, i]

# For each cross section column, find the first index with non-missing
# values and copy these to the missing elements below.
for i in range(u_cross_filled.shape[-1]):
    column_vals = u_cross_filled[:,i]
    # Let's find the lowest index that isn't filled. The nonzero function
    # finds all unmasked values greater than 0. Since 0 is a valid value
    # for dBZ, let's change that threshold to be -200 dBZ instead.
    first_idx = int(np.transpose((column_vals > -200).nonzero())[0])
    u_cross_filled[0:first_idx, i] = u_cross_filled[first_idx, i]

# Get the terrain heights along the cross section line
ter_line = interpline(ter, wrfin=wrf_file, start_point=cross_start,
                      end_point=cross_end)

# Get the lat/lon points
lats, lons = latlon_coords(w)

# Get the cartopy projection object
cart_proj = get_cartopy(w)

# Create the figure
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax_cross = pyplot.axes()

# Make the cross section plot for dbz
w_levels = np.arange(-4E-1, +4E-1, 5E-2)
xs = np.arange(0, w_cross.shape[-1], 1)
ys = to_np(w_cross.coords["vertical"])
w_contours = ax_cross.contourf(xs,
                                 ys,
                                 to_np(w_cross_filled),
                                 levels=w_levels,
                                 cmap='seismic',

                                 extend="both")
# Add the color bar
cbar = fig.colorbar(w_contours, ax=ax_cross)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
cbar.set_label('Vertical Velocity (m.s)', rotation=-270, fontsize=12)
# Fill in the mountain area
ht_fill = ax_cross.fill_between(xs, 0, to_np(ter_line),
                                facecolor="black")

# Tentativa do quiver

ax_cross.quiver(xs[::5], ys[::5],
          to_np(u_cross_filled[::5, ::5]), to_np(w_cross_filled[::5, ::5]*100))

# Set the x-ticks to use latitude and longitude labels
coord_pairs = to_np(u_cross.coords["xy_loc"])
x_ticks = np.arange(coord_pairs.shape[0])
x_labels = [pair.latlon_str() for pair in to_np(coord_pairs)]

# Set the desired number of x ticks below
num_ticks = 5
thin = int((len(x_ticks) / num_ticks) + .5)
ax_cross.set_xticks(x_ticks[::thin])
ax_cross.set_xticklabels(x_labels[::thin], rotation=90, fontsize=8)

# Set the x-axis and  y-axis labels
ax_cross.set_xlabel("Latitude, Longitude", fontsize=12)
ax_cross.set_ylabel("Altura (m)", fontsize=12)

# Add a title
ax_cross.set_title("Ilha com vetores zonais", {"fontsize" : 14})

pyplot.show()

fig.savefig('WV.png', dpi=None, facecolor='w', edgecolor='w',
        orientation='portrait', papertype=None, format=None,
        transparent=False, bbox_inches=None, pad_inches=0.1,
        frameon=None, metadata=None)
```

[image: result from script]

Comment: Thank you very much for this code. Quick question: why have you multiplied the w_cross_filled by 100? Is it so that the vertical component of the wind (which is often overshadowed by horizontal winds) shows more? And would this not undermine the accuracy of the vectors?

Comment: multiplying w by 100 is just for scaling purposes since its values are rather small (~ x10-2)